# WSO2 showing same basic user profile for external LDAP users

Tags: ldap, wso2

I'm setting up a new wso2 AMI manager instance.  I've updated the user store to point to an external read only LDAP server. When I log into /carbon I can see the list of users coming back from the LDAP server, but when I click profile for any of the users I get the same profile (with the admin account name) instead of that users profile.

The new wso2 server is using AMI version 2.6.0. We have an older server with version 2.0.0 on it that does work using the same LDAP settings.

I tried changing one of the claims for wso2.org/claim to point to a different attribute coming back from the ldap server but that did not change what was being displayed on the users profiles.

When I click on any of the users names, here is what gets displayed in the profile. (I hid service account name and role)

- Profile Name * default
- First Name  *
- Last Name  *   NameofServiceAccount
- Organization
- Country
- Email  *
- Telephone
- Mobile
- IM
- URL
- Role   Internal/everyone,XX-XX-XX-XX-Services
- Department

Does anyone know why all the users profiles return what appear to be the same record? Does anyone have any ideas what I could do to further debug the issue? I believe that the LDAP is returning correctly.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thanks Updated to show actual question.